# Fixing nested for loop in python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will compute values of wavelengths in such a way that for while n = 1, it checks the values for k = 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. And I need to to do that up to n = 4, with 5 sequential integers k starting from n + 1. IE if n = 3, check for k = 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8. So there will be a total of 20 wavelengths. The code I currently have prints out 20 wavelengths, with the first one being correct for each n, but the next 4 are incorrect. I'm not sure how to fix this, please help

```
for n in range (1, 5):
    for k in range (2, 7):
        k = n + 1
        RH = 1.09678e-2
        waveLength = 1 / (R_H * (1/n**2 - 1/k**2))
        print(waveLength)
```

Comment: What should the result look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner loop is using the same `k = n + 1` value every time, not using the value of `k` that comes from `range(2, 7)`.

The range in the inner loop needs to be based on `n`, not fixed numbers.

```
for n in range(1, 5):
    for k in range(n+1, n+6):
        RH = 1.09678e-2
        waveLength = 1 / (R_H * (1/n**2 - 1/k**2))
        print(waveLength)
```

Another way to do it would be to use `range(1, 6)` in the inner loop, and add the two values:

```
for n in range(1, 5):
    for m in range(1, 6):
        k = n + m
        RH = 1.09678e-2
        waveLength = 1 / (R_H * (1/n**2 - 1/k**2))
        print(waveLength)
```

Comment: The result isn't different from OP's

Comment: Yes it is. He's ignoring the inner range, because he sets `k = n + 1`.